# C# Naudio I wish to stream a song over the Network using AudioFileReader

Tags: c#, stream, naudio

Is it possible to add **Network stream** to **AudioFileReader**, so I can send it over a **network**

```
            waveOut.Init(AudioReader);
            waveOut.Play(); waveOut = new WaveOut();
            AudioReader = new AudioFileReader("d:/ANYA - Beautiful World.mp4");
            waveOut.Init(AudioReader);
            waveOut.Play();`
```

I have created a working **TCP Network Audio Chat App** and I wish to send a **song** over the network

I would be gratefull for code to do this ...

Thank you
DK

Comment: Did you try passing the network path to `AudioFileReader`!?

Comment: Hi  do you mean

            byte[] samples = new byte[1024];

            while (reader.Read(samples, 0, samples.Length) > 0)

            {

                stream.Write(samples, 0, samples.Length);
            }

Comment: AutodioFileReader class does not have constructor which accepts byte array or stream as parameter. It only accepts the filename. So you need to pass the network path of the audio file in `new AudioFileReader`.